# merger two list of dictionaries with common key

Tags: python

I have 2 list of dictionaries:-

```
 x = [{'Name': 'SG', 'State': 'All good'}, {'Name': 'AA', 'State': 'All good'}]


y = [{'Name': 'SG', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started'},
 {'Name': 'AA', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started'}]
```

Would like to merge them both with y showing as:

```
y = [{'Name': 'SG', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started', 'State: 'All good'},
 {'Name': 'AA', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started', 'State: 'All good'}]
```

Below code does not give the desired result:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for k, v in x[i]:
        y[i][k] = v
```

NOte: x and y both the list have the same number of dictionaries and both have a matching "Name"

Comment: You probably wanted `for k, v in x[i].items():`.  You should be getting an error there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way that does the same as what I think you're trying to do in your code:

```
>>> for d1, d2 in zip(x, y):
...     d2.update(d1)
... 
>>> y
[{'Name': 'SG', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started', 'State': 'All good'}, {'Name': 'AA', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started', 'State': 'All good'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionnaries are perfectly matching by pairs, look `@Iguananaut` solution

---

If not, and you have to check the `Name` field, I'd suggest you  build intermediate dict `{Name:value}`, then you iterate to retrieve the possible informations in both, that allow to have missing values (missing Name) in any of the dict

```
x = [{'Name': 'SG', 'State': 'All good'}, {'Name': 'AA', 'State': 'All good'}]
y = [{'Name': 'SG', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started'},
     {'Name': 'AA', 'Alias': 'blue', 'Status': 'Started'}]

prepare_x = {row['Name']: row for row in x}
prepare_y = {row['Name']: row for row in y}

result = [{**prepare_x.get(key, {}), **prepare_y.get(key, {})}
          for key in (prepare_x.keys() | prepare_y.keys())]
```